# MVC3 / Partial Views / Multiple Paginated Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm, viewmodel, partial-views

**How to I render out two paginated lists on my Home Page?**

I am willing to do what it takes - If it means tailoring my code to fit a solution or tailoring an existing solution to fit my code.

I have successfully rendered one paginated list to the home page using a partial view.

Take a look at my code:
Views
..Home > Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var m in Model.First)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("FirstSummary", m);
}
<div class="pager">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Views
..Shared > FirstSummary.cshtml

```
@model MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities.First
@{
    if (@Model.IsActive)
    {
    <div class="first-list-item">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="first-name">
                    @Model.Property.ToString() 
                    @Model.Property.ToString()
                    @Model.Property.ToString() -
                    @Model.Property.ToString() 
                    @Model.Property.ToString()
                    @Model.Property.ToString()
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "First", new { area = "", id = @Model.FirstId }, new { @class = "button" })
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
}
```

}

Controllers > HomeController.cs

```
        public ViewResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        FirstListViewModel viewModel = new FirstListViewModel
        {
            First = repository.First
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.FirstId)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.First.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Models > FirstListViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities;

namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.Models
{
    public class FirstListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<First> Firsts { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModels > FirstAndSecond.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MovinMyStuff.WebUI.Models;
namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.ViewModels

namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.ViewModels
{
    public class MovesAndMovers
    {
        public MovesListViewModel movesList { get; set; }
        public MoversListViewModel moversList { get; set; }
        public MovesAndMovers()
        {
            movesList = new MovesListViewModel();
            moversList = new MoversListViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the way I handle this kind of stuff is with knockoutjs and ajaxing back to get the data I want.  But that might be a bit of a drastic change.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Any recommended articles on integrating KnockoutJS into MVC3 with some use cases? I'm interested in this library.

Comment: I have used backbone.js. Is that similar to knockout.js? If so I would have to do some re-architecting...lol. ( :

Comment: it is similar HelloJonny....  so you could use that

Comment: @SergioTapia,  well, knockoutjs is done by one of the guys at MS,  it comes preboxed in MVC4 which is what I'm using....  not sure on articles.   A lot of the people on the knockout forum are doing asp.net MVC and knockout.  Mostly its straightforward, though I do remember at the beginning I had a lot of fluffing around trying to hook it all up and had to change the way I thought about doing things a little bit! I did see someone post this http://knockoutmvc.com/  the other day.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT! This was quite a beast of a task...I have spent nearly 10 hours trying to solve this so please stay tuned as I WILL GIVE WHO EVER WANTS THIS the answer. Now all I have to do is prevent the refresh from sending me back to the top of the page. Yikes! That will hopefully not be so bad... ( :